# MSVC Loading DLLs from SysWOW64 for my 86x Application

Tags: c++, dll

**Hello!**

I'm a begginer to C++ and i've been trying to compile an open source application 86x. Well, after facing many errors and problems. I finally generated the .exe, but when I try to open, it crashes.
So, I've noticed that the MSVC is loading DLLs for a 64 system, correct me If I'm wrong, and it's not loading symbols from the SDL.dll and gmp.dll, also I think it's not adding symbols to the xxxx.exe(released).
Then, it's exiting with error (0x1) that means something is wrong.

*Help me out please! :)*

Heres the compiler relase info:

```
 'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Release\xxxx.exe'. Module was built without symbols.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Release\SDL.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Release\SDL_gfx.dll'. Symbols loaded.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Release\gmp.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcp90.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
    'xxxx.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
    The program '[4468] xxxx.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Debbuging info:

```
error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Debug\xxxx.exe 
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ)    C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(fonts.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ)    C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(list.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ)   C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(fonts.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ)   C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(list.obj)c
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(struct std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Has_debug_it)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@U_Has_debug_it@01@@Z)  C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(fonts.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(struct std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Has_debug_it)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@U_Has_debug_it@01@@Z)  C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(messagebox.obj)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QBEXXZ)  C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(fonts.obj)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_empty<class std::allocator<class glictContainer *> >::_Container_base_aux_alloc_empty<class std::allocator<class glictContainer *> >(class std::allocator<class glictContainer *>)" (??0?$_Container_base_aux_alloc_empty@V?$allocator@PAVglictContainer@@@std@@@std@@IAE@V?$allocator@PAVglictContainer@@@1@@Z)  C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(container.obj)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::~_Container_base_secure(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base_secure@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "protected: __thiscall std::_Container_base_aux_alloc_empty<class std::allocator<class glictContainer *> >::~_Container_base_aux_alloc_empty<class std::allocator<class glictContainer *> >(void)" (??1?$_Container_base_aux_alloc_empty@V?$allocator@PAVglictContainer@@@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ)   C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(container.obj)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(struct std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Has_debug_it)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@U_Has_debug_it@01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall glictContainer::glictContainer(void)" (??0glictContainer@@QAE@XZ) C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(container.obj)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base_secure::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base_secure@std@@QBEXXZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall std::vector<class glictContainer *,class std::allocator<class glictContainer *> >::_Tidy(void)" (?_Tidy@?$vector@PAVglictContainer@@V?$allocator@PAVglictContainer@@@std@@@std@@IAEXXZ)   C:\Users\Xabirau\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\GLICT_mtd.lib(container.obj)
```

Comment: These are not "compiler code", just notifications from the debugger when it sees a DLL getting loaded into a process.  SysWow64 is the home directory for executable files that will be loaded into the Wow64 emulator.  Which is an emulator that enables executing 32-bit programs on a 64-bit operating system.  You'll need to learn to use the debugger to diagnose the problem in your program.  Using the Debug configuration is important.  And don't randomly change VS configuration unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: To Hans Passant: Thank you for the help! I've edited the question with the debbuger info. Is this Debbuger that you meant?

Comment: Sigh, you are a million miles removed.  Go slow, you'll need to do the small programming exercises first.

Comment: Haha, Hans, indeed. I should take some programming exercises. And this is my exercise. Learning in the hard way :). Can you help me out, master ?

Comment: The LNK2001 errors are linker errors, so how do you run it to debug?

Comment: David: That's the problem, when the app runs it crashes. And I just can't find what or why it's linking wrong. Since its added into Linker/Input and to its VC++ Directories.

Comment: @Xabirau: What David is implying, you are running the last version of your app that did not have a LINK2001 error. You are not running the version which corresponds too your current code.

Comment: MSalters: Oh, I see. So, should I try it out in an earlier version? or Try to update the code to the current version?

Comment: @Xabirau - you need to resolve the LNK errors so that you can a good build, then worry about any runtime errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SysWow64 is the 32 bits Windows subsystem on a 64 bits Windows OS. This part is expected.

The error is therefore probably an ordinary error somewhere in your program. Run it in the debugger - yes, release builds also can be run in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for answering me! I've edited the post with the known errors from the debug. I'm not sure if these errors are linked with the compiler release info. Do you have any further guesses for my problem?